# animateTransform not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make a SVG group follow a SVG path and transform animate the group.  I am trying to make #moon transform with animateTransform but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone spot the problem?

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 570 594" preserveAspectRatio="true" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="padding: 0 10px 0 18px;fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-miterlimit:10;">
    <path id="orbit" d="M146.719,183.637l-18.408,-7.796l-13.233,-6.252l-12.327,-6.302l-18.44,-9.379l-12.42,-11.695l-16.36,-10.421l-15.546,-10.511l-12.326,-12.281l-14.415,-14.728l-8.426,-16.45l-4.168,-14.276l2.084,-14.272l6.297,-11.239l8.019,-10.103l12.013,-6.302l16.682,-8.426l16.356,-4.169l22.804,-4.217l27.474,-4.168l22.03,0l21.75,1.042l24.881,1.042l20.524,1.042l26.875,3.126l27.917,5.211l41.477,9.293l37.047,10.702l41.159,12.782l35.33,14.012l19.808,8.426l25.874,12.554l18.86,11.423l18.578,11.556l18.815,14.105l17.777,16.951l12.233,16.718l8.345,17.187l1.091,27.64l-7.434,8.207l-11.194,10.466l-15.595,10.559l-24.221,7.844l-22.609,5.211l-30.925,3.265l-43.658,0l-32.546,-2.085" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0px;stroke:#ff6060;"/>
    <g id="moon" style="transform: translateY(-130px) translateX(-53px);">
        <path d="M77.39,295.34c0,-10.683 -8.658,-19.343 -19.342,-19.343c-10.683,0 -19.344,8.66 -19.344,19.343c0,10.683 8.661,19.343 19.344,19.343c10.684,0 19.342,-8.66 19.342,-19.343" style="fill:#fff;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
        <path d="M61.54,304.476c0,-2.967 -2.404,-5.373 -5.371,-5.373c-2.969,0 -5.373,2.406 -5.373,5.373c0,2.967 2.404,5.373 5.373,5.373c2.967,0 5.371,-2.406 5.371,-5.373" style="fill:#878787;fill-opacity:0.199997;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>

        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlink:href="#orbit" />
        </animateMotion>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 60 70"
                      to="360 60 70"
                      dur="10s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing a CSS transform with the SMIL animation of a transform attribute. Although SVG 2 suggests they should be the same thing, SVG 1.1 has them as different things. Until the SVG 2 specification and UAs implementation of SVG 2 gets closer to completion it's best not to mix these things.

I've converted the g element's transform to an attribute transform and the animations certainly seem to do something for me now on Firefox.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 570 594" preserveAspectRatio="true" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="padding: 0 10px 0 18px;fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-miterlimit:10;">
    <path id="orbit" d="M146.719,183.637l-18.408,-7.796l-13.233,-6.252l-12.327,-6.302l-18.44,-9.379l-12.42,-11.695l-16.36,-10.421l-15.546,-10.511l-12.326,-12.281l-14.415,-14.728l-8.426,-16.45l-4.168,-14.276l2.084,-14.272l6.297,-11.239l8.019,-10.103l12.013,-6.302l16.682,-8.426l16.356,-4.169l22.804,-4.217l27.474,-4.168l22.03,0l21.75,1.042l24.881,1.042l20.524,1.042l26.875,3.126l27.917,5.211l41.477,9.293l37.047,10.702l41.159,12.782l35.33,14.012l19.808,8.426l25.874,12.554l18.86,11.423l18.578,11.556l18.815,14.105l17.777,16.951l12.233,16.718l8.345,17.187l1.091,27.64l-7.434,8.207l-11.194,10.466l-15.595,10.559l-24.221,7.844l-22.609,5.211l-30.925,3.265l-43.658,0l-32.546,-2.085" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0px;stroke:#ff6060;"/>
    <g id="moon" transform="translate(-53, -130)">
        <path d="M77.39,295.34c0,-10.683 -8.658,-19.343 -19.342,-19.343c-10.683,0 -19.344,8.66 -19.344,19.343c0,10.683 8.661,19.343 19.344,19.343c10.684,0 19.342,-8.66 19.342,-19.343" style="fill:#fff;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
        <path d="M61.54,304.476c0,-2.967 -2.404,-5.373 -5.371,-5.373c-2.969,0 -5.373,2.406 -5.373,5.373c0,2.967 2.404,5.373 5.373,5.373c2.967,0 5.371,-2.406 5.371,-5.373" style="fill:#878787;fill-opacity:0.199997;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>

        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlink:href="#orbit" />
        </animateMotion>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 60 70"
                      to="360 60 70"
                      dur="10s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't seem to get keyTimes and values attributes to work.  Are these deprecated and replaced by from and to?

Comment: Your question has no keyTimes attribute, ask another question that does have that and I'll try to see what's wrong with it. keyTimes and values are not deprecated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951291/animatetransform-not-working-for-transform-scale

Answer (score -1):

Easy !

**AnimateTransform** tag has to be *within*

**AnimateMotion** tag, completely enclosed, not following.

Comment: The animateMotion works but animateTransform does not work.  Could you clarify your answer?  (I did not downvote).

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the animateTransform **is** within the `<g>` tag that it's animating and it doesn't have to be within either as it could be given an xlink:href attribute and then put anywhere.

Comment: Simply move </AmimateMotion> to after </AnimateTransform> I will posted one of my examples.

Comment: That isn't the problem either.

Comment: Also Chrome is fussier than Firefox and Opera.

Comment: In my experience Firefox is the fussiest, Chrome and Opera use the same rendering engine so they will always be identical.

Answer (score -1):

Precessing Orbit:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="940" height="360"  viewBox="0 0 350 350"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<!-- Here is a red circle which will be moved along the     motion path. -->
<g>
  <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45            0,1 10,110"
      stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" 
      fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/
  <circle cx="470" cy="180" r="160" fill="paleblue" />     
  <circle cx="10" cy="110" r="3" fill="lightgrey"  />
  <circle cx="110" cy="10" r="3" fill="lightgrey"  />
        <circle cx="" cy="" r="10" fill="red">        
    <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
    <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 440 190"
                      to="360 440 190"
                      dur="6s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
       <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
 </circle>
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 60 70"
                      to="360 60 70"
                      dur="10s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>

</g>                   
</svg>
```

Copy, paste, edit to your liking.

Comment: having an animateTransform in an animateMotion is not valid.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div width="100%">
<svg style="background:plum" width="240px" height="120px"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

<polygon points="60,30 90,90 30,90">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 60 70"
                      to="360 60 70"
                      dur="10s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</polygon>
</svg>
</div>
```